# Java SSL pre-shared key mode in JSSE

Tags: java, android, ssl, encryption, cryptography

I'm developing secure communication framework for PC and Android mobiles, without using certificates and public key exchange. Pre-shared key will be used.

The framework has it's own protocol for authentication and key exchange.

The procedure is the follows:

1. Hosts authenticate to each other
2. After two communicating hosts are authenticated to each other, they share session private key.
3. Traffic between hosts is encrypted using that key.

I plan to use SSL for traffic encryption, but without using and third-party SSL library (only standard JSSE facilities).

Actually, SSL will be used only for traffic encryption (key exchange and authentication is already made).

How it's possible to explicitly set pre-shared key for SSL?

If it's not directly supported by JSSE, but can be made by overriding default SSL classes (SSLEngine, SSLSocketFactory, and etc), how to do it? What classes can be responsible for it?

Comment: It seems like you are re-inventing SSL. Why?

Comment: Not reinventing, i plan to use SSL, but without PKI, certificates, and etc. It's a peer-to-peer framewok, and it's needed to remove any centralized control (certificates and CAs in particular).

Answer (score 1):

SSL/TLS lets you use several mechanisms for authentication besides certificates, eg. you can use shared secret (PSK cipher suites) or OpenPGP keys and more. However, not many implementations actually support those mechanisms. I don't know whether Java built-in cryptography supports them. Our SecureBlackbox does support all mechanisms defined in TLS specifications including those I've mentioned.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Shared secret will be used for SSL.

Comment: Java SE JSSE of Oracle does not contain shared secret implementation AFAIK.

Comment: What's about making own implementation of Java SSL classes (SSLEngine, SSLSocketFactory and etc) ?

Comment: @АндрейМосквичёв Emm, are you asking how you can make them or .. ? If you mean adding such thing to SecureBlackbox, then we have such idea in our wishlist. You can vote for it on https://www.eldos.com/sbb/wishlist.php?vox_idea_id=418

Comment: No, i'm talking about JSSE, not SecureBlackbox. Is there any way to override default Java SSL behavior by deviring SSLEngine, SSLSocketFactory and etc classes?

Comment: @АндрейМосквичёв yes, SSL engines are replaceable and you can plug your own. But this is a totally different question.

Comment: It's not a different question. SSL classes replacement is directly related to this question.

Comment: @АндрейМосквичёв It's not related to my answer. If you want to amend your question - do this. Asking unrelated questions as comment to answers makes no sense on StackOverflow.

Comment: Your answer is not an answer to my question, but advertising of your product. It's great, that your SecureBlackbox support this feature, but i need SSL pre-shared key mode without using third-party products.

Comment: @АндрейМосквичёв StackOverflow doesn't work this way. If you want to ask a different question - post it as a different question. Asking new questions in comments won't give you answers. Is it so hard to comprehend?

Comment: This doesn't answer his question he asked about using JSSE not your product maybe your answer would be as a comment.

Comment: @Dean re-read  the OP's comments: "Is there any way to override default Java SSL behavior by deviring SSLEngine, SSLSocketFactory and etc classes". The question is how to get PSK cipher suites (in general). The answer is "no way with default Java's TLS engine".

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp You should update your answer instead of having this in the comments. As in your answer you state: "I don't know whether Java built-in cryptography supports them."

Answer (score 0):

You can find open source TLS PSK JSSE socket factories powered by Bouncy Castle and released under the Apache v2 license here: https://github.com/clover/pskfactories

The project includes example usage.

Alternatively WolfSSL also appears to have a JSSE implementation that supports PSK. It's powered by native code so likely a bit more work to get up and running than if it was pure Java. It's also GPLv2 unless you purchase a commercial license.

See https://www.wolfssl.com/products/wolfssl-jni-jsse/